# Imported pytorch-lightning, but spyder seems unable to find it

Tags: python, pytorch, spyder, pytorch-lightning

I need to `import LightningModule` from `pytorch_lightning`.
I didn't have `pytorch_lightning` so I installed it and when I launch the code, I have a `ModuleNotFoundError`, telling me that there is `No module named pytorch_lightning`.

First question is : the module that I installed includes `LightningModule`, but is called `pytorch-lightning` instead of `pytorch_lightning`, can that be the source of the problem ?
If it can't, does anybody have an idea for a solution ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Ensure in which python environment your dependency is installed.

Did you create a dedicate python virtualenvironment? or did you installed in your system environment?

Below script works as expected

```
# create virtualenvironment
python -m venv venv

# enable it
.\venv\Scripts\activate # WIN system
source ./venv/bin/activate # LINUX system

# install dependency 'pytorch_lightning'
python -m pip install pytorch_lightning
```

---

Import your class in the PYTHON REPL (or wherever you want)

```
(venv) C:\Users\bigmauri\workspace\test>python
>>> import pytorch_lightning
>>> pytorch_lightning.LightningModule
<class 'pytorch_lightning.core.module.LightningModule'>
```

---

doc **pythorc-lightning** [here](https://github.com/LinHangzheng/pytorch-lightning#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

Moving forward with PyTorch Lightning 2.0, correct way of installation is - `pip install lightning`

```py
import lightning as L

class Model(L.LightningModule):
    ...


trainer = L.Trainer()
```